# Calling camera app recreates android activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-tabhost, android-camera

I am working on a tabbed activity which is implemented using ActivityGroup. When I call the camera app and returns back its always calling **onCreate()** and recreates the activity. Because of this the callback to **onActivityResult** is having a null data.

I am adding this inside manifest file. But no change.

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

I am having this issue only on samsung galaxy s3. I have tested the same on galaxy s2,HTC, galaxy nexus. All devices works fine.

How can I do this properly?

Thanks