# Returning from camera app recreates tabhost

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost, android-camera

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling camera app recreates android activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335357/calling-camera-app-recreates-android-activity)

I am creating a tabbed activity in android.Inside one of the activities within a tab I launch the camera app using startActivityForResult(). After returning from camera my tabhost is recreated. So I am taken back to the initial screen of the tab.

I have added this line for tabhost and all the activities of the tab. But still the same.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

How can I prevent tabhost reloading/recreation?

Thanks

Comment: You can get back to your tab by tabHost.setCurrentTab(id); but my guess that you are finishing your activity after you start the camera activity, am I right? if so, do not.

Comment: You can't. Every Android app should deal with an activity being destroyed and recreated.  Save state in onPause() and restore it in onResume() including what tab is selected.

Comment: @Simon  Issue for me is onActivityResult will have a null data when its getting called. Is there any solution for that? Will your suggestion resolve my issue? Can you provide any sample code to do this please.

Comment: @KirillKulakov no I am not calling finish. I can see this happens only on s3. On s3 when camera app starts its changing the orientation to landscape and back. is that the reason for my error?